# Azure Service Fabric - Web Api on Owin - https problems

Tags: azure, ssl, web, owin, azure-service-fabric

Trying to enable https on my Web Api running on self hosted Owin in Azure Service Fabric (local debugging to start with). Have followed the steps in [this blog](https://matt.kotsenas.com/posts/https-in-service-fabric-web-api)

My applicationmanifest.xml looks like this:

```
  <ServiceManifestImport>
    <ServiceManifestRef ServiceManifestName="TheNetPkg" ServiceManifestVersion="1.0.0" />
    <ConfigOverrides />
    <Policies>
      <EndpointBindingPolicy EndpointRef="serviceendpoint" CertificateRef="mycertificate" />
    </Policies>
  </ServiceManifestImport>
  <DefaultServices>
    <Service Name="TheNet">
      <StatelessService ServiceTypeName="TheNetType" InstanceCount="[TheNet_InstanceCount]">
        <SingletonPartition />
      </StatelessService>
    </Service>
  </DefaultServices>
  <Certificates>
    <EndpointCertificate X509StoreName="MY" X509FindValue="‎‎‎‎[thumbprint]" Name="mycertificate" />
  </Certificates>
</ApplicationManifest>
```

Servicemanifest.xml

```
<Endpoints>
  <Endpoint Name="serviceendpoint" Type="Input" Protocol="https" Port="8087" />

</Endpoints>
```

Regarding the certificate (self signed made with makecert) I have verified that it exist in Certificates (Local Computer) -> Personal -> Certificates

I imported the certificate with powershell

```
 Import-PfxCertificate -Exportable -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\My -FilePath [pathtocertificate\cert.pfx] -Password (Read-Host -AsSecureString -Prompt "Enter Certificate Password")
```

I have verified that the web api works with http, but then when trying to deploy to the local cluster the Node wont start. When trying to debug what is going on, none of the breakpoints are ever hit.

Have been reading that other people had to enter the thumbprint key one char at the time, that doesn't seem to work either.

Any suggestions to what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the thumbprint being wrong after all!

The one I had entered manually was incorrect so I tried to copy paste it from MMC console instead. First into Notepad where I hit delete on the first character to remove any "invisible characters" other people have been having issues with. That did not work, Service Fabric still crashed.

I then pasted the thumbprint copied from Notepad into Powershell and noticed a character looking like a square before the thumbprint. Removed that square in Powershell and pasted the thumbprint into my config file.

Tried to build, but no! Visual Studio complained that I was missing a whitespace (??). I then inserted a line break between EndpointRef and CertificateRef. Published once again to my local cluster, and now it works.